# How would I make a long embed split into multiple embeds

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to figure something out. If someone sends an embed to an application system I am making and it's over 2000 characters, it will not send. Is there a way to fix this as it gets really annoying asking the people to manually do it. If you have some information or code to share please send it.

Is there just a basic way to make an embed over 2000 characters into multiple separate embeds?

Comment: Just use Discord.js's Util.Splitter class, it handels everything for you, you just need to make a loop to create and send the embeds

Answer (score 1):

Discord has a Util Class which exposes a Splitter util.
By using this code as below, you can maximise the text in one embed ( up to ~ 6000 chars ), if you need more, you could use this system 2 times, once for creating a 2nd (or more) embed and let embed to use 6000 chars.

Additionaly I think the if is redundant and you do not need it.

```
const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setColor(helper.normalcolor);
embed.setTitle(`lyrics for: ${data.data[0].artist} : ${data.data[0].name}`);
embed.setColor(helper.normalcolor);
const lyrics = getLongString();
if (lyrics.length >= 2048) {
    const ly = Discord.Util.splitMessage(lyrics, {
        maxLength: 1024,
        char: '\n',
        prepend: '',
        append: '',
    });
    embed.setDescription(ly.shift());
    ly.forEach((i) => embed.addField('\u200B', i));
}
else {
   embed.setDescription(lyrics);
}
message.channel.send(embed);
```